# how to show image form resource as stream with php

Tags: php, oracle, image, oracle-apex

im retrieving image from oracle blob field that is uploaded via oracle apex. field value is resource( type Stream).  how may i show image in img tag with php?

im using this code

```
  $query='select ID,IMAGE from student where BATCH_ID='.intval($_GET['batchid']);

 $list=$diu_db->select($query);
  foreach($list as $item){

   echo $item['IMAGE'];
   // print_r($item['IMAGE']);     // shows resource id ....
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Start buffering the output stream
ob_start();

// output the image as a file to the output stream
Imagejpeg($im);

//Read the output buffer
$buffer = ob_get_contents();

//clear the buffer
ob_end_clean();

//use $buffer as you wish...
```

Comment: imagejpeg(): supplied resource is not a valid Image resource

Comment: resource type : Stream

Answer (score 0):

Use header to notify browser what image type you are sending. Something like:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

Or similar for your image type.
Set this header `before` you print image content.

Comment: i have used header('Content-Type: image/jpg'); but image empty.

Comment: Is your image content valid in database? Describe empty.

Comment: image is perfectly viewed in oracle apex form

Comment: Let's say your image is `.jpg`. Content type should be `image/jpeg` in that case

Comment: my image is `.jpg` and i used `image/jpeg` not showing image